# Euler Lagrange equations, chain rule troubles

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule, euler-lagrange-equation

When considering the first integral the chain rule is used on

$$F(y,y’,x)$$

When we do this why do we not consider it as

$$F(y(x))$$ 
As y’ is a function of y

But instead as y’ being a separate variable? And so gets it’s on partial derivative in the chain rule?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1109623/11127 ,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580858/11127 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451