# Derivative of $f(\theta(t)))$ with respect to the derivative of $\theta$, i.e. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{\theta}}$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose I have an angle $\theta(t)$ as a function of time, and I'm considering the expression

$$f(t) = \dot{\theta}\sin(\theta)$$

Is it true that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = \sin\theta
$$

Or would we have something like
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = \sin\theta + \dot{\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\left(\sin\theta\right)
$$

I guess I'm confused because both $\theta$ and $\dot{\theta}$ are functions of time, so I feel like the derivative should be more complicated than just $\sin\theta$. For example, could we write

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial \dot{\theta}}{\partial t}\right)^{-1} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left(\ddot{\theta}\right)^{-1}
$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $\frac{\operatorname dy'}{\operatorname dy}$ zero, since $y'$ depends on $y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580858/why-is-frac-operatorname-dy-operatorname-dy-zero-since-y-depends-on)

Comment: @HansLundmark It certainly seems related but I haven't studied the Lagrangian, so I'm not sure if all of the information maps to this case?

Comment: OK. But if I may ask just out of curiosity: if you're not studying Lagrangian mechanics (or calculus of variations), then where did you encounter derivatives with respect to $\dot\theta$?

Comment: I am studying a crank-slider mechanism and using a numerical method to simulate the movement of the linkages. The linkages are modeled as vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\dot\theta\sin\theta$ is a function of $\dot\theta$ and $\theta$ its partial derivatives w.r.t. $\dot\theta$ and $\theta$ are astonishingly simple, namely $\sin\theta$ and $\dot\theta\cos\theta$. I have deliberately not given that function a name, because writing $f(t)$ for it is when the confusion starts. Better to write
$$
f(t)=\dot\theta(t)\sin(\theta(t))=g(\dot\theta(t),\theta(t))\,.
$$
Then, by the chain rule,
$$
\dot f(t)=(\partial_{\dot\theta}g)\frac{d\dot\theta}{dt}+(\partial_\theta g)\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\ddot\theta(t)\sin(\theta(t))+\dot\theta^2(t)\cos(\theta(t))\,.
$$