# Euler-Lagrange equation partial derivative

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm curious about Euler Lagrange equation. $$d/dx(dF/dy') - dF/dy.$$
$y=y(x)$ why when we partial derivative $dF/dy'$ we don't need to consider $x$ or $y$?
like $dF/dx * dx/dy'$

Comment: Because at any given point $x$, the values $y(x)$ and $\dot y(x)$ are independent. The aim of the variational calculus is to end up with such a functional relation between the values and derivatives of $y(x)$.

Comment: Is ˙(), x also independent?

Comment: Yes, in the linearization step of the action integral variation you just have a function $F(x,y,v)$ of independent variables $x,y,v$. The total derivative you get from the conversion of $\delta v=\delta\dot y$ to $\delta y$ via partial integration, this explicitly deals with changes along the path $y(x)$ and $v(x)=\dot y(x)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580858/11127 and links therein.